# ¿Cómo asignar otro orden predefinido a las columnas en PANDAS?

Tags: python, pandas

Hola tengo el siguiente ajuste en PANDAS

```
df = pd.DataFrame(table_rows,columns=('COD','COLOR','TALLA','')).sort_values(by=['COD']
dff = df.groupby(['COD','COLOR','TALLA']).sum().unstack(fill_value=0).reset_index()
```

Lo cual me bota una tabla con las columnas mencionadas y luego la columna de las tallas (La suma acumulada) pero en orden alfabético (M L S XL). Lo que deseo es saber si hay una manera para asignarle el siguiente orden (S M L XL).
Me podrían ayudar. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Imaginando un `df` como este:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Talle": ["XL", "L", "M", "M", "L", "S", "XL", "S"]})
df.sort_values("Talle", inplace=True)
print(df)

  Talle
1     L
4     L
2     M
3     M
5     S
7     S
0    XL
6    XL
```

Es claro que el orden por Talle es meramente alfabético, si queremos ordenar realmente por el talle, podemos convertir está columna en una [categoría](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html) y definir el orden de cada nivel:

```
df["Talle"] = pd.Series(pd.Categorical(df.Talle, categories=["S", "M", "L", "XL"]))
df.sort_values("Talle", inplace=True)
print(df)

  Talle
4     S
5     S
2     M
3     M
1     L
0     L
7    XL
6    XL
```